# Android Cursor Index out of Bound Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

is there any thing wrong with this code, i want to query for data by using barcode and it show me that Cursor Index out of Bound exception .

```
public String getIdByBarcode(String ss) throws SQLException{
    String[] column = new String[]{Pro_ID,Pro_Barcode, Pro_Name,Pro_NameKhmer, Pro_Quantity, Pro_Price, Pro_Description, Pro_Date};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, column, Pro_Barcode + "= '" + ss + "' " , null, null, null, null);

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String id = c.getString(0);
        Log.v(id, id + "Id" );
        return id;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No results in the `Cursor`. You should check what `moveToFirst()` is returning (most likely `false`). Also you should use `moveToNext()`, not `moveToFirst()`. Also watch out that you're not checking `ss` parameter. This could lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. You should be using parameters. Also I think you can use a single return in your method.

```
public String getIdByBarcode(String ss) throws SQLException {
    String[] column = new String[]{Pro_ID,Pro_Barcode, Pro_Name,Pro_NameKhmer, Pro_Quantity, Pro_Price, Pro_Description, Pro_Date};
    final String args = new String[1];
    args[0] = ss;
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, column, Pro_Barcode + " = ?" , args, null, null, null);
    String ret = null;
    if(c.moveToNext()) {
        ret = c.getString(0);     
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The literature of moveToFirst() method:

> **public abstract boolean  moveToFirst ()**  Move the cursor to the first row.  This method will return false if the cursor is empty.
>
> **Returns** whether the move succeeded.

So your moveToFirst call is failing(because cusrsor has 0 elements) and that is the reason for crash.

Do this:

```
if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    String id = c.getString(0);
    Log.v(id, id + "Id" );
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String id;
if (c!= null && c.moveToNext){
   String id = c.getString(0);
   return id;   
 }
```

Comment: Using a while here just makes no sense. `id` will always be getting the last element. Not to mention `id` is not accessable from outside the loop...